# Swift - Stop iCloud mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification for entity

Tags: swift, core-data, icloud

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "persistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChanges:", name:NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification, object: coordinator)


func persistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChanges(notification: NSNotification) {
    let dictionary = notification.userInfo!
    println(dictionary)
    var moc: NSManagedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext!
    moc.performBlock { () -> Void in
        moc.mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification(notification)
    }
}
```

on `println(dictionary)` i got this;

```
[inserted: {(
    0x7a1111f0 <x-coredata://5D1E5D9E-BB22-445E-BF1F-9E7012381FA1/People/p5>,
    0x7a115620 <x-coredata://5D1E5D9E-BB22-445E-BF1F-9E7012381FA1/Settings/p5>
)}, deleted: {(
)}, updated: {(
)}]
[inserted: {(
    0x78ed06f0 <x-coredata://5D1E5D9E-BB22-445E-BF1F-9E7012381FA1/People/p6>,
    0x78e94ae0 <x-coredata://5D1E5D9E-BB22-445E-BF1F-9E7012381FA1/Settings/p6>
)}, deleted: {(
)}, updated: {(
)}]
```

**Question**

1. How to prevent inserting of Settings ?
2. How to find if dictionary inserted info it will be in Settings ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't prevent it. When you call `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification` you merge all changes from the save notification. There's no customization.

You can control *how* the changes are merged by using `NSManagedObjectContext`'s `mergePolicy` setting. That affects how data loaded by `moc` is affected when you merge changes-- whether to keep in-memory changes or to overwrite them, for example. Built-in merge policies include things like `NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicyType` and `NSOverwriteMergePolicyType`, or you can create your own custom policy.

Trying to prevent it doesn't make sense anyway. The whole point of merging changes here is that these changes have already been saved to the persistent store file, and you're making sure that `moc` knows about those changes. If you somehow prevented `moc` from knowing about changes to one entity type, those changes would still exist, only now `moc` would be out of date.